# Are terminals in EBNF searched directly?

Tags: compiler-construction

I was looking at a parser grammar in EBNF and I saw that some of the terminals such as parentheses, semicolons, and other single character tokens were added to the grammar directly, enclosed by quotes, rather than with their respective token names. Does this mean that the parser reads from stdin directly when searching for that character, rather than calling the scanner?

Comment: This would depend on which parser and parser generator you’re using, but almost certainly it would be calling the scanner because the input to a parser is typically a sequence of tokens. Can you edit the question to include the specific snippet you were looking at and which tool it was for?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the source you were looking at was a yacc-like parser generator. Those allow single character tokens (only!) to be represented as that single character surrounded by single quotes (eg `'+'`). Any single-byte character can be used (except NUL), including those which need to be written with a C escape, such as `'\n'`. This can make grammars much more readable and avoids have to think up token names for punctuation.

Bison also lets you write a multi-character token (or any token) with an *alias*, which is a double-quoted string (eg. `"while"`). However, these must be given token names so that the scanner can return the token, and the name and alias need to be declared with a `%token` directive:

```
%token T_DO "do" T_IF "if" T_ELSE "else" T_WHILE "while"
```

For both single-quoted and aliased tokens, the scanner must cooperate. All input is performed by the scanner. The parser has no interface which permits it to directly read input.

In yacc/bison, tokens are just small integers; in the generated header, there is an `enum` declaration which associates each token name with it's corresponding token number. The assignments start with 257. 256 is reserved for the `error` pseudotoken, 0 for the end-of-input pseudotoken, and 1 through 255 for single characters. The scanner indicates which token type it has encountered by returning the token code. If the code for a `(` token is the character itself, then the scanner can `return '(';`.

Nothing aside from the programmer's sense od decency forces the scanner to return the correct code. And if a token has an alias is used, the scanner has no way of knowing that, so again nothing forces the alias to be the actual keyword. (Aliases can be used for patterned tokens, too; this allows for translation of generated error messages.)

I strongly recommend using these features if you use bison, even though the grammar might not be as portable, because a syntax is much more readable with actual keywords:

```
iteration: "for" '(' opt_expr ';' opt_expr ';' opt_expr ')' statement
```

Automatic translation of error messages is also helpful. To avoid confusion, I don't uses aliases I declare for this purpose in productions. (For translation to work, it's sufficient to declare the alias.) But that's just my personal style. It's not a requirement.